# MySql CSV import from MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, phpmyadmin, dump

I've got a CSV file exported by MSSQL. When I try to import it into MySql, PhpMyAdmin returns  "Invalid column count on line 2316". I don't know why. Can you help me? heres the code around line 2316:

```
2312: 708;Nein;0;;Ja;Nein;0;Ja;;Ja;;Ja;;Ja;;8;;5;;;;Ja;Nein;Nein;Ja;Nein;Nein;Nein;Ja;Nein;Ja;Nein;Nein;Nein;Nein;Ja;Nein;Ja;Nein;Nein;Nein;Nein;Nein;Nein;Nein;Nein;Nein;Ja;Nein;Nein;Nein;Nein;Ja;Nein;Nein;Nein;Ja;1;Nein;;Nein;;Nein;;Ja;1;Nein;;Nein;;;5;Nein;;;Hildebrecht, Susanne;;040-65432154;tut@web.de;;;1
2313: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
2314: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
2315: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
2316: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Charset of the File is UTF-8 and the Database has utf8_general_ci. MySql Version is 5.1.43-nmm4-log.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer: http://andrewodendaal.com/phpmyadmin-invalid-field-count-in-csv-input-on-line-1/ 
OR
Quick fix for this problem is to change the delimiter symbol manually. Use semicolon ( ; ) as field delimiter instead of comma ( , ).

Comment: I tried it this way, but my MySql user does not have the rights to use LOAD DATA..

Comment: grant file on *.* to user@hostname identified by 'password'; Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file

Comment: I solved it by using the command-line at another server using the mysql --infile opperator (or something similar). I don't have the code I handled it with here, right now. Sorry!